# как открыть программу через python код в ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ubuntu

Как из python-кода запустить нужную мне программу (например PyCharm) если программа была установлена через менеджер приложений ubuntu?

Comment: Не уверен, что это хороший вариант, но можно попробовать через `os.system()`, передав в качестве аргумента строку с командой запуска Вашей программы.

Comment: А если я не знаю где именно стоит программа и она не запускается через терминал?

Comment: Любая программа должна запускаться через терминал. А вот поиск бинарника и вообще удобство такого запуска — уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Запустить ярлык из меню можно так

```
gtk-launch jetbrains-datagrip
```

Имя смотрите в папках `/usr/share/applications/`, `~/.local/share/applications`, `/usr/share/local/applications/`.